# Meaning of => operator in the c# code

Tags: c#

I have following c# code.
i don't know the meaning of `=>` operator in this code!!

```
public class ClassA: ClassB
{
    public string Type => "article";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a shorthand syntax that was introduced in C# 6. The sample that you provided is a shorthand for readonly property and it is equivalent to

```
public class ClassA: ClassB
{
    public string Type 
    {
        get { return "article"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: man...this is too much sugar. I will probably slap whoever does this lol

Comment: @Steve: less typing? ... and less is better when ReSharper forces you to drop typing speed by 20%. >P

Comment: @Steve, really ... I would follow the older way to be more readable.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322096/11683